# Virtual function to file in C++

Tags: c++

I'm just wondering if it is possible to write in a dynamic array object which consist of virtual function, `display()` to a text file (eg. `txtfiletodisplay.txt`).

edited:
instead of using vector, im implementing it this way.

in main()

```
clsStaff** objStaff = new clsStaff[userInput];

ofstream outputFile("staff.txt");

for (x=0; x<userInput; x++)
      outputFile = objStaff[x]->display();
```

Comment: please be clear, what excatly you want to do ?

Comment: or to ask it the other way round, why do you seem to believe that you can't do it? or why not simply try it?

Comment: Sounds perfectly possible to me.

Comment: A [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) containing objects that have a `display` member function?

Answer (score 0):

```
class FileDisplayer
{
public:
     virtual File display() const;
     ...
};

class File
{
    ...
};

std::vector<FileDisplayer*> objStaff; // this
FileDisplayer* objStaff[100];         // ... or this
FileDisplayer** objStaff;             // ... or this

File outputFile = objStaff[x]->display();
```

No idea what you really mean, so `FileDisplayer` and `File` might be misleading names.

EDIT:

It might be that display is meant to take outputFile as a parameter (and outputFile is an output stream). In that case the above should be rewritten like this

```
class FileDisplayer
{
public:
     virtual void display(std::ostream& file) const;
     ...
};

std::vector<FileDisplayer*> objStaff; // this
FileDisplayer* objStaff[100];         // ... or this
FileDisplayer** objStaff;             // ... or this

std::ofstream outputFile;
...
objStaff[x]->display(outputFile);
```

Comment: is it possible to do it if i'm not using vector?

Comment: Of course, just replace the vector with an array, or a pointer if you want a dynamic array. See edit above.

Comment: may i ask what is the class File written above is used for? i want to understand the reason why you implement a File in front of the outputFile. or to be more exact, i understand that it's a misleading name. but why it's necessary to include a File which is a class name in front of outputFile.

Comment: outputFile is a variable, all variables must be declared before they are used. You declare a variable by prefixing it with it's type. That's what I did above. Of course I made up `File` for all I know you might have already declared outputFile as something else.

Comment: alright, i get what you're trying to implement now. My outputFile was declared as ofstream as edited earlier. So I implement it based on my own coding as posted above. But there is a problem which i don't understand. I get an error instead saying that there is no match "operator <<" in outputFile. Does this mean that in the file i/o concept, an ofstream variable basically couldn't read a dynamic array which contain let's say a number of staff in the objStaff.

Comment: @user2949294 It's not completely clear to me what you are trying to do. ofstream variables are for *writing* not for *reading*. I'm sure what you want to do can be done, it's just since I don't know what that is it's hard to advise. It might be that what you want is this `objStaff[x]->display(outputFile);`, i.e. you should change `display` to take outputFile as a *parameter*, not have display *return* an ofstream (which doesn't make a lot of sense). It's a big difference between a function parameter, and a function return value, you need to be clear which you want.

Comment: yes you answered my question. i'm sorry that i confused you. cause i wrote a LOT of code without realising that I provide you the wrong information in the first place. yup your post above helped me. thanks